# Now laravel model instace not have any attribute

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

i have update my table in the database and add new column user_id but when i create new model instance i don't find this column as attribute, actually i don't have any attribute in the model instance

**Model**

```
class Event extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
   
    public $timestamps = true;
    protected $fillable = ['reminder_id','title','start_at','end_at','all_day','description','folder_task_id','user_id'];

    // relations 
    public function folder_task()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(FolderTask::class);
    }

    public function timer()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Timer::class);
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
$this->event = new Event();
dd($this->event);
```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`Laravel` uses an [active records pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern) for the models. In this design pattern / architecture. The `Model` will not know it's columns, before they hit the database. Fillable is not a definition, more of a guard to ensure, you can't overwrite all columns from requests or similar.

In your example your `Model`, has not been saved in the database and therefor does not have any attributes. If you create the `Model` with data it will show.

```
$event = new Event(['title' => 'Your title','start_at' => now(),'end_at' => now()]);
$event->save();
dd($event); // attributes will be 'title', 'start_at' and 'end_at'
```

Or similar if you fetch the Model, it will also show the attributes, as it will fetch it will read the columns from the database.

```
dd(Event::find(1)); // attributes will be all columns from the database
```

Comment: If the answer helped this problem, you can accept it as an answer :)